# iOS: CloudKit perform(query: ) does nothing - closure not executed

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I am in process in adding CloudKit to my app to enable iCloud sync. But I ran into problem with my method, that executes query with perform method on private database.

My method worked fine, I then changed a few related methods (just with check if iCloud is available) and suddenly my perform method does nothing. By nothing I mean that nothing in `perform(query: )` closure gets executed. I have breakpoint on the first line and others on the next lines but never manage to hit them.

```
private static func getAppDetailsFromCloud(completion: @escaping (_ appDetails: [CloudAppDetails]?) -> Void) {

        var cloudAppDetails = [CloudAppDetails]()
        let privateDatabase = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: APPID_Type, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE"))

        privateDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                completion(nil)
            } else {

                if let records = records {

                    for record in records {
                        let appId = record.object(forKey: APPID_ID_Property) as? Int
                        let isDeleted = record.object(forKey: APPID_ISDELETED_Property) as? Int

                        if let appId = appId, let isDeleted = isDeleted {
                            cloudAppDetails.append(CloudAppDetails(id: appId, isDeleted: isDeleted == 1))
                        }
                    }

                    completion(cloudAppDetails)
                    return

                }
            }
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
```

My problem starts at `privateDatabase.perform` line, after that no breakpoints are hit and my execution moves to function which called this one getAppDetailsFromCloud. There is no error...

This is my first time implementing CloudKit and I have no idea why nothing happens in the closure above.

Thanks for help.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that this metod used to work fine and I was able to get records from iCloud. I have not made any edits to it and now it does not work as described :/

EDIT 2: When I run the app without debugger attached then everything works flawlessly. I can sync all data between devices as expected. When I try to debug the code, then I once again get no records from iCloud.

Comment: "My problem starts at privateDatabase.perform line"  Your problem probably starts at the line right above that one.

Comment: Check that APPID_Type is a valid type name in your CloudKit scheme.

Comment: @Adolfo it is, I forgot to mention that I managed to get all my records with this method before I made changes to the other ones.

Comment: @ElTomato what do you mean exactly? I had this working before and havent made any changes specifically to this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the completion handler shown here, if there's no error and no results are found, execution will fall through and quietly exit. So, there are two possible conditions happening here: the query isn't running or the query isn't finding any results. I'd perform the following investigative steps, in order:

1. Check your .entitlements file for the key `com.apple.dev.icloud-container-environment`. If this key isn't present, then builds from xcode will utilize the development environment. If this key is set, then builds from xcode will access the environment pointed to by this key. (Users that installed this app from Testflight or the app store will always use the production environment).
2. Open the cloudkit dashboard in the web browser and validate that the records you expect are indeed present in the environment indicated by step 1 and the container you expect. If the records aren't there, then you've found your problem.
3. If the records appear as expected in the dashboard, then place the breakpoint on the `.perform` line. If the query is not being called when you expected, then you need to look earlier in the call stack... who was expected to call this function?
4. If the `.perform` is being called as expected, then add an `else` to the `if let record` statement. Put a breakpoint in the else block. If that fires, then the query ran but found no records.
5. If, after the above steps, you find that the completion handler absolutely isn't executed, this suggests a malformed query. Try running the query by hand using the cloudkit dashboard and observing the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed steps to take. I have no idea what is happening in my app. When I launched it without debugging (the same code that does not work as described) everything works fine and all my data syncs between iPhone and iPad. Debugging is still the same problem + I even managed to get some millions of records from CloudKit which then couldnt be used... I am pretty confused

Comment: another update. I disabled most of my breakpoints and tried debug because I wanted to test another stuff and suddenly my last breakpoint (which I forgot to turn off) was hit. This seems like my "excessive" breakpoint usage somehow broke CloudKit... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The closure executes asynchronously and usually you need to wait few seconds.

Take into account you can't debug many threads in same way as single. Bcs debugger will not hit breakpoint in closure while you staying in your main thread.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

2019, I encountered this issue while working on my CloudKit tasks. Thunk's selected answer didn't help me, so I guess I'm gonna share here my magic. I got the idea of removing the breakpoints and print the `results` instead. And it worked. But I still need to use breakpoints inside the closure. Well, what I had to do is restart the Xcode. You know the drill in iOS development, if something's not right, restart the Xcode, reconnect the device, and whatnot.

[image]